# Trying to implement hide keyboard when clicking anywhere besides textfield in swift

Tags: swift, mobile, keyboard, hide

I am able to type in the password textfield and click anywhere outside and have the keyboard hidden but whenever i type into the email textfield and click anywhere besides the textfields or login button I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit

 class FirstScreen: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!


     @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UITextField!



     @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)
     {
         self.passwordLabel.resignFirstResponder()
         self.emailLabel.resignFirstResponder()
         /*
         let emailLabel1 = emailLabel.text!
         let passwordLabel1 = passwordLabel.text!
         if((emailLabel1.contains("email")) && (passwordLabel1.contains("password")))
         {


         }
         else
         {
              print("ERROR")
         }*/

     }
      override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         self.view.endEditing(true)
      }


 }
```

And here is the error I get:

```
 2020-01-16 17:43:44.645152-0500 Workout Log[3413:176741] -[Workout_Log.FirstScreen 
 emailLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf95503920
 2020-01-16 17:43:44.670234-0500 Workout Log[3413:176741] *** Terminating app due to 
 uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Workout_Log.FirstScreen 
 emailLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf95503920'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c91fd4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480c0f17 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 302
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c75c4c ___forwarding___ + 1436
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c77f78 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48093fff -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a6c00e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a6c358 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 398
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48387616 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 155
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480c01b3 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 358
11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4838725c -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 48
12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480c0315 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 275
13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff483870d6 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 93
14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839f01d -[UIView(UITextField) endEditing:] + 184
15  Workout Log                         0x0000000103cf1c8e $s11Workout_Log11FirstScreenC12touchesBegan_4withyShySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSgtF + 334
16  Workout Log                         0x0000000103cf1d38 $s11Workout_Log11FirstScreenC12touchesBegan_4withyShySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSgtFTo + 136
17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480bf863 forwardTouchMethod + 340
18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480bf6fe -[UIResponder touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480ce8de -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1867
20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d04c6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4596
21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480ab53b -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4812c71a __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 6847
23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4812f1e0 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5980
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4471 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd439c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd3b74 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce87f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
29  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
31  Workout Log                         0x0000000103cefccb main + 75
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
 )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Been trying to fix this for a while so any help would be great

edit:

I tried implementing the following code but still get the same error:

```
import UIKit

class FirstScreen: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UITextField!

func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

 }

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
 }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    dismissKeyboard()
}

@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    self.emailLabel.resignFirstResponder()
    self.passwordLabel.resignFirstResponder()
    /*
    let emailLabel1 = emailLabel.text!
    let passwordLabel1 = passwordLabel.text!
    if((emailLabel1.contains("email")) && (passwordLabel1.contains("password")))
    {


    }
    else
    {
        print("ERROR")
    }*/

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}




 }
```

Comment: Does the app crash as soon as the screen loads? From the error message it looks like the IBOutlet for the emailLabel is not hooked up to your storyboard.

Comment: I've connected and reconnected emailLabel to the controller like 3 times lol. Still getting the same error. And no it only crashes when i attempt to click outside after typing in emailLabel.

Comment: @RichardDesouza have you tried the below answer?

Comment: @chirag90 I tried using your code but still get the same error. Please see the code above

Comment: @chirag90 Actually I just replaced the textfield with a new variable and now it works. Thanks for the help anyway guys

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below, call it from `viewdidload`

```
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {        

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

 }

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The button is referencing to a @IBAction method type which doesn't exist any more. Usually it means that @IBAction method name or type was changed and a storyboard relation to that method was not updated.

**Solution:**

In Storyboard remove an action attached to `Touch Up Inside` and reconnect it one more time to a method:

> @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)